# Написал бота для майнкрафта на Python, который может отвечать на сообщения, но на определённых игроков не работает

Tags: python, бот, minecraft

Написал бота на Python с библиотекой mineflayer

```py
@On(bot, 'chat')
    def msgHandler(this, user, message, *args):
        user_parts = message.split(' ', 3)
        if len(user_parts) > 1:
            full_user = user_parts[1]
            clean_user = str(full_user)
            clean_user = clean_user[:-1]
        if '>info' in message:
            bot.chat('Приветсвую, это бот ne_blitziwster, дс: blitziwster Бот создан на Python, пока в разаботке, если вы тоже хотите учавствовать в бета тесте или предложить идею, пишите в дс, чтоб ознакомится со списком комманд, напишите: >help (1-2)')

        if '>help 1' in message:
            bot.chat('Список команд: >info информация о боте, >help (1-2) список команд, >tp бот телепортируется к игроку написавшему команду, >walk бот преследует написавшего игрока, >write (сообщение) бот пишет сообщение которые вы написали')

        if '>help 2' in message:
            bot.chat('>invite/remove (ник) добавляет/убирает в список пользователей бота')
```

при этом, бот отвечает только на игроков у которых в нике, квадратных скобках английский текст -> [iomanip] MINIST blitziwster, а если у них в скобках ничего нету или русский текст [] MINIS blitziwster, [ишак] MINIST blitziwster, то бот не отвечает на их команды

Comment: Если разобрались, добавьте ответом. Решение должно быть в ответе, а не в вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я исправил это, надо было изменить *событие* с chat(принимает сообщения от игроков) на messagestr(принимает все сообщения, даже от сервера и плагинов), *событие* chat считал сообщения от игроков которые в клане с Русским названием и игроков без клана, как сообщения от сервера, поэтому *событие* не считало такие сообщения, за сообщения от игроков:

```py
@On(bot, 'messagestr')
def handleServerMsg(this, message, *args):

    user_parts = message.split(' ', 3)

    if len(user_parts) > 1:
        full_user = user_parts[2]
        clean_user = str(full_user)[:-1]
        if clean_user in data:

            if '>tp' in message:
                user_parts = message.split(' ', 3)
                user_parts = user_parts[4] if len(user_parts) > 4 else clean_user
                bot.chat(f'Телепортируюсь к {user_parts}!')
                bot.chat(f'/call {user_parts}')
```

Answer (score -2):

Честно не знаю как на питоне это сделать, но на NodeJS код будет выглядеть так:

```js
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer');
const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
  host: "IP",
  port: "PORT",
  version: "VERSION",
  username: "BOT_NICKNAME"
});
bot.on('message', (jsonMsg) => {
  let mes = jsonMsg.toString()
  console.log(mes.split(' ')[0].replace('<', '').replace('>', '')) # Отправлем в консоль никнейм игрока
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).